# Laravel doesn't show copied URL image inside home.blade.php

Tags: html, laravel

Laravel doesn't show image with copied URL. I tried everything and i also tried reading stackoverflow questions about this but nothing helped.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <p>Test</p>
        <img src="https://scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/97566921_2973768799380412_5562195854791540736_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s320x320&_nc_ht=scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=K6wOdgtL1C4AX8vXQK-&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT-CZthKcVgpzi71lCY9fRYyPC8kf4yq5ecZ_zeV5pG6dw&oe=62C1C25F&_nc_sid=7bff83" alt="image" height=200 width=200>
</div>
<div class="col-9">

</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

The image shows when i open it in browser (https://scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/97566921_2973768799380412_5562195854791540736_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s320x320&_nc_ht=scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=K6wOdgtL1C4AX8vXQK-&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT-CZthKcVgpzi71lCY9fRYyPC8kf4yq5ecZ_zeV5pG6dw&oe=62C1C25F&_nc_sid=7bff83)

But it doens't show on the website. This is home.blade.php

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @ac.0101010111 
home:1 Uncaught (in promise) Object
home:1 Uncaught (in promise) Object
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/bootstrap.esm.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: @ac.0101010111 Ooh i also get this: GET https://scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/97566921_2973768799380412_5562195854791540736_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s320x320&_nc_ht=scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=K6wOdgtL1C4AX8vXQK-&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT-CZthKcVgpzi71lCY9fRYyPC8kf4yq5ecZ_zeV5pG6dw&oe=62C1C25F&_nc_sid=7bff83 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin 200

Comment: Try adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute in your `<img>` tag

Comment: Still getting errors:
Access to image at 'https://scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
home:69          GET https://scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/97566921_2973768799380412_5562195854791540736_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s320x320&_nc_ht=scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=K6wOdgtL1C4AX8vXQK-&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT-CZthKcVgpzi71lCY9fRYyPC8kf4yq5ecZ_zeV5pG6dw&oe=62C1C25F&_nc_sid=7bff83 net::ERR_FAILED 200

Comment: @ac.0101010111 Nothing worked but i got the image from another source so now it worked. Thanks for checking the errors in the browser console. I didn't think about that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to call image link with http not https like that :

```
<img src="http://scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/97566921_2973768799380412_5562195854791540736_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s320x320&_nc_ht=scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=K6wOdgtL1C4AX8vXQK-&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT-CZthKcVgpzi71lCY9fRYyPC8kf4yq5ecZ_zeV5pG6dw&oe=62C1C25F&_nc_sid=7bff83" alt="image" height=200 width=200>
```

Comment: No doesn't work either. This is weird right?

Comment: @ProgrammerFromHolland because if you call image with https inside who has a host no secure the images not shown

Comment: But i am also gettings error:
Access to image at 'scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com' from origin '127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. home:69 GET scontent-ams2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/… net::ERR_FAILED 200

Comment: You have probleme with cors, the website owner block to show image in any website, you can try this chrome extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Comment: Didn't work either but i picked the image from another source.